# PLS-00201: identifier 'COL1.POTO' must be declared

Tags: sql, pls-00201

Hi I have problem with  variable:

[image]

Here is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure WstawPotomka(  wPesel IN    Osoba.Pesel%TYPE, wImie IN Osoba.Imie%Type ,
wNazwisko IN    Osoba.Nazwisko%TYPE,  wDataUr IN Osoba.Data_Urodzenia%Type,    wMiejsceUr IN Osoba.Miejsce_Urodzenia%Type, PeselMatka IN    Osoba.Matka%Type, PeselOjciec IN Osoba.Ojciec%Type) 
AS Cursor Potomek    
IS SELECT 
o.pesel as Col1, b.pesel AS Col2, c.pesel AS Col3 FROM    OSOBA o 
CROSS JOIN Osoba b 
CROSS JOIN Osoba c; 
poto Potomek%ROWTYPE;    
BEGIN 
OPEN Potomek; 
LOOP 
FETCH Potomek INTO poto; 
EXIT WHEN    Potomek%NotFound; 
IF Col1.poto != wPesel THEN    
IF COL2.poto = PeselMatka and COL3.poto = PeselOjciec THEN 
INSERT INTO Osoba Values (wPesel, wImie, wNazwisko, wDataUr, wMiejsceUr,    null, PeselMatka, PeselOjciec, null); 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END LOOP; 
Close Potomek; 
END;
```

The Osoba table:

[image]

It's my first post so don't be so angry for formatting.

Comment: It's `poto.Col1` instead of `Col1.poto`.

Comment: Please stop using `OPEN` / `FETCH INTO` / `EXIT WHEN` / `CLOSE`. Use the much simpler cursor FOR LOOP instead, introduced about 20 years ago.

Comment: And if your stored procedure should be performant, replace the entire loop with a single `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a single efficient SQL statement.

I highly doubt that the SELET statement and the general logic in your code is correct. CROSS JOINs create a cartesian product and are always suspect. But even worse: The inserted rows only take data from the input parameters and thus are all the same. The SELECT statement only determines the number of rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WstawPotomka(
    wPesel      IN  Osoba.Pesel%TYPE,
    wImie       IN  Osoba.Imie%TYPE ,
    wNazwisko   IN  Osoba.Nazwisko%TYPE, 
    wDataUr     IN  Osoba.Data_Urodzenia%TYPE,
    wMiejsceUr  IN  Osoba.Miejsce_Urodzenia%TYPE,
    PeselMatka  IN  Osoba.Matka%TYPE,
    PeselOjciec IN  Osoba.Ojciec%TYPE
) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Osoba
    SELECT wPesel, wImie, wNazwisko, wDataUr, wMiejsceUr, NULL, PeselMatka, PeselOjciec, NULL
    FROM    OSOBA o 
    CROSS JOIN Osoba b 
    CROSS JOIN Osoba c
    WHERE o.pesel <> wPesel
      AND b.pesel = PeselMatka
      AND c.pesel = PeselOjciec;
END;
```

Comment: I think you forgot "BEGIN" ater "AS".
Thank you for all your replies. It was very helpful.

Comment: Indeed. I've fixed it.